# Why the const value can be changed using pointer inside the stack.?

Tags: c

The const value can be changed inside the stack using pointer.But we can not modify the value of a const variable when it is defined globally.Because it goes to the RO data section.So this value is protected.But inside a stack the const variable doesn't provide protection.Why..?..If it is not providing any protection means then what is the use of const value inside the stack.?.

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: Changing `const` variable's value invokes undefined behavior, please don't do it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `const` keyword you just tell the compiler to throw error when you try to assign this variable, but it doesn't protect memory.